# JS one-liner filter similar objects from 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to filter 2 arrays that have similar objects.

`genreFiltered` returns correctly

`sortFiltrered` should return an aray with 5 objects like the `recommended` Array.
Instead it returns empty.

Can someone spot **what i'm doing wrong with the way i'm filtering the 2 arrays in `sortFiltrered`?**

```
let genreFiltered = genreValue !== 15 ? games.filter((game) => game.genre_id === genreValue) : games

let sortFiltrered= sortValue !== 1 ? genreFiltered.filter((game) => game.game_id === recommended.filter((rec) => rec.game_id)) : genreFiltered

console.log('recommended', recommended)
console.log('genreFiltered', genreFiltered)
console.log('sortFiltrered', sortFiltrered)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: You are trying to compare game.game_id with an array so the filter function returns false. Hence no match found and empty array returned.

Comment: I believe recommended.filter((rec) => rec.game_id) returns an array and you want to check it against string

Comment: I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be equal ... You should get at least the first element.

```
let ageFiltrered = sortValue !== 1 ? genreFiltered.filter((game) => game.game_id === recommended.filter((rec) => rec.game_id)[0].game_id)
```

That code will filter all those that have a game_id, and the it will check first ocurrence.

If you want to not only check the first occurence you can do something like that (it is just a simple example but you can use it in your case):

```
var arr = [{w:'2'}, {w:'3'}, {w:'12'}, {w:'456'}]
arr.filter(w => w.w.indexOf(arr.filter(w => w.w === '22').map(w => w.w).join()) !== -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

well, in this part

```
 genreFiltered.filter((game) => game.game_id === recommended.filter((rec) => rec.game_id))
```

`game.game_id` seems to be an integer and the result of `recommended.filter((rec)` is an array. So, they are not `===`.

Maybe you could use `==` if you know that the result of `recommended.filter((rec) => {...})` is an array with 1 element. Then it will be casted to a string like '1' and then with `==` operator it will be casted to an integer so that `1 == [1]` will give you `true`.